# How to change DataFrame column dtype with regex and lambda expression?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['123','667','323'],
                   'b':['8000','1. 300', '56'],
                   'c':['11','apple', '100']})

#      a       b      c
# 0  123    8000     11
# 1  667  1. 300  apple
# 2  323      56    100
```

I want to change the data type to int if it's a string of numbers. The regular expression is easy enough:

```
pattern = '^\d+$'
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

How to change the data type to `int` of any column that matches (column a in this example)? The column names are not consistent so I can't hard-code it. Do I need applymap here?

Comment: kindly post the expected output

Comment: Why not just `df[col].astype(int, errors='ignore')?`

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on each column to use [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html), as follows:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(int, errors='ignore'))
```

Result:

```
df.to_dict()

{'a': {0: 123, 1: 667, 2: 323},          
 'b': {0: '8000', 1: '1. 300', 2: '56'},
 'c': {0: '11', 1: 'apple', 2: '100'}}
```

Column `a` has been converted to `int` type.

---

We can also make use of your approach to get the columns convertible to `int`, and then convert the columns accordingly:

Use [`.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) on default `axis=0` to flag those columns with all row elements  matching your regex pattern.  Then, use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to locate those columns and get the column names into the list `cols`.   Then, convert type to `int` with [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) on this list of columns:

```
import re

pattern = '^\d+$'
cols = df.loc[:, df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)).all()].columns

df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)
```

Result:

```
df.to_dict()

{'a': {0: 123, 1: 667, 2: 323},          
 'b': {0: '8000', 1: '1. 300', 2: '56'},
 'c': {0: '11', 1: 'apple', 2: '100'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are maybe looking for [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```py
ret = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
print(ret.dtypes)
```

The above expression applies `pd.to_numeric()` to each column of the data-frame, see [`pd.DataFrame.apply(fun, **kwargs)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). This is roughly equivalent to the dtype inference of [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for *numeric* data in .csv files. With `pd.to_numeric()`, you have the possibility to convert non-matching expressions to NaN (set `errors="coerce"`), or apply additional downcasting of the inferred types (add argument `downcast="signed"`).

I see that this is not exactly answering the OP's question (no regex involved). However, I'd rather use the dtype inference functionality offered by pandas than develop one myself.

Comment: I saw pd.to_numeric when searching but didn't think it would work due to other strings. The errors="ignore" is very helpful, thanks.